# After clicking on a custom button on Account page, I want to autopopulate a custom field of Opportunity

Tags: button, custom

Apex:

```
global class AccountClass {
    Webservice static void populateOpportunity(Account id1) {
        List < Account > acclist = new List < Account > ([Select AccountCreationDate__c from Account]);
        List < Opportunity > opplist = new List < Opportunity > ([Select Accountid, OpportunityCreationDate__c from Opportunity]);

        for (Opportunity opp: opplist) {
            if (id1 = opp.Accountid)
                //AccountCreationDate__c is a custom field in Account
                //OpportunityCreationDate__c is a custom field in Opportunity
                OpportunityCreationDate__c = AccountCreationDate__c;
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}
if({!Account.id}!=Null) {
 sforce.apex.execute("AccountClass","populateOpportunity",{Id:"{!Account.Id}"}"});
 alert("This is {!Account.Name}");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of issues here, including an assignment in an `if` statement instead of a comparison and two unbounded queries.

```
        if (id1 = opp.Accountid)
```

`=` is an assignment. `==` is a comparison.

```
    List < Account > acclist = new List < Account > ([Select AccountCreationDate__c from Account]);
```

Your Account query needs a SOQL filter, `WHERE Id = :id1`.

```
    List < Opportunity > opplist = new List < Opportunity > ([Select Accountid, OpportunityCreationDate__c from Opportunity]);
```

Your Opportunity query needs a SOQL filter, `WHERE AccountId = :id1`. Alternately, you could write these two queries as a single SOQL parent-child query.

Then you can remove your `if` statement entirely, since you're working only with the data you actually want.

As a best practice, you should always use braces around the body of your `if` statements and other control flow constructs. While it's legal to omit them for one-statement blocks, it tends to lead to confusing mistakes.

Lastly, you do not perform any DML to persist information back to the database. At the conclusion of your method you should be doing

```
update opplist;
```

I strongly recommend that you complete introductory modules on Trailhead, like [Apex Basics and Database](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database). You need to establish good foundations in how Salesforce works to make sure your code is effective and you're able to debug it.